# Get word at cursor in zsh function

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to set up some fancy zle completion that requires passing the word at point to a subprocess.

Zsh obviously knows about the current word/token/directory, and I can see how to bind things based on the current word, but I can't figure out how to turn "where I am" into a variable capable of being passed into subprocesses. (I want emacs' [thing at point](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPoint) but in zsh.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a simple zle widget `print-current-word` to illustrate how you can extract the current word on the command line in simple cases, i.e. assuming that blanks are *always* word separators. (So this fails when quoting or escaped blanks come into play):

```
print-current-word() {
  CURRENTWORD="${LBUFFER/* /}${RBUFFER/ */}"
  print; print "The current word is: $CURRENTWORD"
}
zle -N print-current-word
```

- `$LBUFFER` and `$RBUFFER` contains the command line left and right from the cursor, respectively.
- `${name/pattern/repl}` return the variable *name* with *pattern* replaced with *repl*. So in that case this trims in `$LBUFFER` everything up to the last blank, leaving the portion left of the cursor of the current word. Analog for `$RBUFFER`.

---

A more complicated approach would be:

```
print-current-word () {
    local words i beginword
    i=0 
    beginword=0
    words=("${(z)BUFFER}") 

    while (( beginword <= CURSOR )); do
            (( i++ ))
            (( beginword += ${#words[$i]}+1 ))
    done
    CURRENTWORD="$words[$i]"
    print; print "The current word is: $CURRENTWORD"
}
```

However, this one is also not free of assumptions, as it is assumes that every word is separated by *exactly one* blank (addition of +1 to `beginword`).

Just a few words about some special things:

- `words=("${(z)BUFFER}")` splits `$BUFFER`, i.e. the complete command line, into shell words using shell parsing rules by  *Expansion Flag* `(z)` and puts it into an array
- `(( ... ))` activates zsh's math mode
- `${#name}` gives the length of the variable *name*